# Angular 5 - Dynamic Component Loading - Component placed outside of ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I am for a couple of days trying to get this to work, but it still doesn't I have opend a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769750/angular-5-dynamic-component-loader-cannot-read-property-viewcontainerref-o) yesterday and it brought me a little further but far from what I want.

I have a modal and in it I want to dynamicly load components. The problem was that the `ng-template` wasn't rendered because it was inside an other `ng-template`. That problem got fixed and it renders now, but totaly not in the right place.

[image]

As you can see, it renders the component *and the modal* for some reason just on the main page as you can see. What's supposed to happen is that the component is loaded in the modal. Here you can see the HTML:

[image]

Now my code:

**checklist.component.ts**

```
import {
    AfterViewInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, Input, OnInit, ViewChild,
    ViewEncapsulation
} from '@angular/core';
import {ChecklistDirective} from "./checklist.directive";
import {ChecklistMainComponent} from "./checklist-main/checklist-main.component";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-checklist',
    templateUrl: './checklist.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./checklist.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ChecklistComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('modalElement') modalElement;
    @ViewChild(ChecklistDirective) appHost: ChecklistDirective;

    constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadComponent();
    }

    loadComponent() {

        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ChecklistMainComponent);
        const viewContainerRef = this.appHost.viewContainerRef;
        viewContainerRef.clear();
        const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

    }

}
```

**checklist.component.html**

```
<ng-template #modalElement let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{ 'Checklist'| translate }}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ng-template appHost></ng-template>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="c('Close click')">{{ 'Close'| translate }}</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onConfirm($event)">{{ 'Confirm'| translate }}</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

**checklist.directive.ts**

```
import {Directive, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHost]'
})
export class ChecklistDirective {

  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

}
```

**checklist.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChecklistComponent } from './checklist.component';
import {DirectivesModule} from '../../theme/directives/directives.module';
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {AppCommonPipesModule} from '../../pipes/common.pipes.module';
import {SharedTaskModule} from '../task/shared.task.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    DirectivesModule,
    SharedTaskModule,
    TranslateModule,
    AppCommonPipesModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    ChecklistComponent
  ]
})
export class ChecklistModule { }
```

**shared.checklist.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {PerfectScrollbarModule} from 'ngx-perfect-scrollbar';
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {FormModule} from '../../components/form/form.module';
import { MultiselectDropdownModule } from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect';
import {DirectivesModule} from '../../theme/directives/directives.module';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OwlNativeDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {SharedModalModule} from '../../components/model/shared.modal.module';
import {AppCommonPipesModule} from '../../pipes/common.pipes.module';
import {SharedDirectiveModule} from '../../directives/shared.directive.module';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import {ChecklistComponent} from "./checklist.component";
import {ChecklistMainComponent} from "./checklist-main/checklist-main.component";
import {ChecklistViewComponent} from "./checklist-view/checklist-view.component";
import {ChecklistMutateComponent} from "./checklist-mutate/checklist-mutate.component";
import {ChecklistDirective} from "./checklist.directive";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        PerfectScrollbarModule,
        NgxDatatableModule,
        FormsModule,
        FormModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        MultiselectDropdownModule,
        DirectivesModule,
        OwlDateTimeModule,
        OwlNativeDateTimeModule,
        NgbModule,
        SharedModalModule,
        TranslateModule,
        AppCommonPipesModule,
        SharedDirectiveModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ChecklistComponent,
        ChecklistMainComponent,
        ChecklistViewComponent,
        ChecklistMutateComponent,
        ChecklistDirective
    ],
    exports: [
        ChecklistComponent,
        ChecklistMainComponent,
        ChecklistViewComponent,
        ChecklistMutateComponent,
        ChecklistDirective
    ],
    entryComponents: [ChecklistMainComponent]
})

export class SharedChecklistModule {
}
```

**checklist-main.component.ts**

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {
    CollectionHttpRequestOptions, CollectionHttpResponse,
    OrderByRequestOptions
} from '../../../services/http.service';
import {ChecklistModel} from '../../../models/checklist.models';
import {ChecklistService} from '../../../services/checklist.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-checklist-main',
    templateUrl: './checklist-main.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./checklist-main.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ChecklistMainComponent implements OnInit {

    isLoading = false;
    tableInfo: any = {offset: 0, limit: 10};
    collectionRequestModel = new CollectionHttpRequestOptions();
    collectionResponseModel = new CollectionHttpResponse<ChecklistModel>();

    @ViewChild('myTable') table: any;
    @Input() formData: ChecklistModel = new ChecklistModel();
    @Output() activate = new EventEmitter();

    constructor(private checklistService: ChecklistService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.setPage(this.tableInfo);
    }

    public onSearch(event) {
        this.collectionRequestModel.page = 1;
        this.collectionRequestModel.search = event.target.value;
        this.load();
    }

    load() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        this.checklistService.getCollection(this.collectionRequestModel).subscribe(response => {
            this.collectionResponseModel = response;
            this.isLoading = false;
        });
    }

    onActivate(event) {
        this.activate.emit(event);

        if (event.type === "click") {
            this.loadChecklist(event);
        }
    }

    setPage(pageInfo: any) {
        this.collectionRequestModel.page = (pageInfo.offset + 1);
        this.collectionRequestModel.itemsPerPage = pageInfo.limit;
        this.load();
    }

    onSort(event: any) {
        const sort = event.sorts[0];
        const orderBy = new OrderByRequestOptions();
        orderBy.key = sort.prop;
        orderBy.direction = sort.dir.toUpperCase();

        this.collectionRequestModel.orderBy = [orderBy];

        this.load();
    }

    loadChecklist(event) {
        console.log("Yay");
    }

}
```

**checklist-main.component.html**

```
<div class="header">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success new-checklist-btn">{{ 'New Checklist'| translate }}</button>
</div>

<div class="body">
    <h5>Current Checklists</h5>

    <ngx-datatable #myTable class="material" [rows]="collectionResponseModel.items" [columnMode]="'force'"
                   [headerHeight]="50"
                   [footerHeight]="50" [rowHeight]="'fixed'" [externalPaging]="true"
                   [count]="collectionResponseModel.totalCount" [offset]="tableInfo.offset"
                   [limit]="tableInfo.limit" [loadingIndicator]="isLoading" (activate)="onActivate($event)"
                   (page)='setPage($event)' (sort)='onSort($event)'>

        <ngx-datatable-column name="Naam" prop="name" [flexGrow]="1">
            <ng-template let-row="row" let-value="value" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                {{value}}
            </ng-template>
        </ngx-datatable-column>

    </ngx-datatable>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please create StackBlitz example?

Comment: No sorry I can't. this is part of a bigger project and a lot of it is confidential, so I can't make an example.

Comment: Did you found a solution about this ? Im in the same case...

Comment: @Miaow Well, not really a solution, but what I ended up doing was throwing the whole dynamic loading part away and just loading it as the page loaded.